# Less Robotik alternative of element.value='foo'

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, autofill

Though i am able to **fill a form field** with javascript using `element.value='foo'`.

webPage is not getting aware that value has been filled and submit button is not getting Enabled(problem absent when manually filling)
even if i forcefully enable it with javascript ;there are long Error messages on trying submission.please share if anyway to trick the webpage with javascript or something else ?
i am using Edge(chromium) console to run Javascript.also i don't own the website.

Comment: If you don't own the website, chances are good you're probably not *supposed* to be accessing it with any level of automation...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol autofill is not unethical i think yet i will think again before implementing it on the website.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol please consider following edit to your comment "remove either '_chances are good_' or '_probably_ from your comment.."